# Changing a Toolbar appearance dynamically

Tags: android

I'd like to dynamically change the appearance of a Toolbar in my app. It should work as the Gmail app; whenever you click on an email, the Toolbar changes and there appear buttons, e. g. Bin, Copy, etc. How to do it? I'm pretty stuck here. Thank you.