# How to a create a custom notification menu item in android

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I want to create a custom menu item for notifications, I don't wanna show the notifications number, I just wanna have a boolean value true/false showing a custom animated menu Item.

[image]

I want a similar circle to showed on the top left of my menu item ??

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shared any code, a naive approach could be to change the toolbar menu items (assuming you are using toolbar) dynamically. This might be of some help to you - [Changing a Toolbar appearance dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221251/changing-a-toolbar-appearance-dynamically)

Comment: Thanks ! But I want is to change the menu Item dynamically and not the whole Toolbar, thanks anyway.

Comment: Here's another approach - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006749/change-icons-in-actionbar-dynamically Basically you will be saving reference to the menu and then playing around with anywhere you want. Hopefully this helps!